# Instruct bower to use exact version by default, not range

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, bower-install, semantic-versioning

When one issues a `bower install mypackage --save`, by default, for version, bower uses the tilde range selector (~) prefix for the latest patch version:

```
"angular-ui-grid": "~3.1.0"
```

Because in reality patch versions do cause breaking changes (we've experienced this four times now with our `dependencies` packages), we'd like to change the behavior to use exact version semver instead:

```
"angular-ui-grid": "3.1.0"
```

Is there a way to automatically enforce this or set *exact* match to the default? I can't expect members of the dev team to remember to delete the `~` everytime they add a bower package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you [read the documentation](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install-options)?  It looks like `-E` or `--save-exact` is what you need.

Edit: just tested it.  That's what you need.  Your command would then be

```
bower install mypackage --save-exact
```

If you want to have that be the default, create a [.bowerrc](https://bower.io/docs/config/) in your home directory and/or in the project directory like:

```
{
  "save-exact": true
}
```

Comment: I was just reading the documentation, and thought I might add that Bower also has pre/post install hooks. You could also run a script to check for/remove the ~ in version numbers in the the bower.json file, or (if you're lucky) somehow enforce that the `-E` argument was passed to bower.

Comment: Thanks, Sunil. That is actually very helpful. Trusting developers to remember "--save-exact" isn't realistic when we've got full-stack devs working on front-end code, unfortunately.

Comment: For enforcing `-E`, you can easily make it an alias if you're running a BASH shell.  Something like `alias bower='bower -E'`  This would be placed in the .bash_profile script; or more globally, it can be placed in `/etc/profile`